# How to convert Mybatis Javassist proxies object to source object(unproxy object)?

Tags: mybatis, javassist

Mybatis excute sql and return a Javassist proxies object.

I want to convert Javassist proxies object to source object.

Since sometimes I don't want to pass the proxy object in my code(It will cause association SQL when other framework reflect the object). I want to use the source object(with no proxy).

for example: 
`select * from user where id = 1;`

Mybatis return an Object type : `User$$_jvstec7_0@a5843b`

But I want to convert it to unproxy object: `User@c5641a`

How can I get an unproxy object without set every member field in object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?